# How to transmit a static H.264 file over RTP

Tags: video, media, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I have a file named `video.h264` and my RTSP server code. I want to transmit this file to a video player (such as VLC or FFplay) upon the `PLAY` request. The problem is that I don't know at what time intervals I should transmit NAL units.

If I know the FPS of `video.h264`, then my logic is that I should transmit FPS Access Units (AU) per second, given that each AU results in one video frame after decoding. But then how do I determine where AUs start? Probably there is some indication of them in the NAL header structure?

Or should I just transmit all the NAL units at once in `video.h264` one-by-one without proper timing, since a media player can nonetheless retain the original timing through RTP's `timestamp` field or by some other means?

Answer (score 0):

So I just transmitted the whole `video.h264` file at once and it worked for me. Additionally, this allowed me to test my code in a quick way.

For anyone wondering how to compute RTP timestamps for `video.h264`, here's how: whenever you encounter a new Access Unit (AU), you increment your timestamp by 90 kHz / FPS. To test for an AU, the simplest way is to check a type of each NAL unit for Access Unit Delimiter (AUD), which must be of value 0x09. However, not all valid H.264 files have AUDs. To obtain an H.264 file with AUDs, you can employ FFmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -i http://docs.evostream.com/sample_content/assets/bun33s.mp4 \
    -vcodec h264 -x264opts aud=1 video.h264
```

(Compiled with `--enable-libx264 --enable-gpl`.)